# Convert imperative to functional style using ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm write the code for convert array of number to new datalist using imperative style but i want to convert it to functional style using javascript library like ramdajs

**background of code**
Suppose the dollar value There are 5 coins in total, 25 dollars, 20 dollars, ... 1 dollar. We will have to exchange money for dollar coins. With the least amount of coins

```
const data = [25, 20, 10, 5, 1];
const fn = n => data.map((v) => {
    const numberOfCoin = Number.parseInt(n / v, 10);
    const result = [v, numberOfCoin];
    n %= v;
    return numberOfCoin ? result : [];
  }).filter(i => i.length > 0);
```

the result of this code should be

```
fn(48) => [[25, 1], [20, 1], [1, 3]]
fn(100) => [[25, 4]]
```

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm - how is the input related to the output? Also, your supplied code already works and it isn't really imperative.

Comment: @VLAZ sorry about that, I forgot to explain the background of this. I edited this post just now.

Comment: Note that neither this code nor the answer from @customcommander gives the least number of coins.  (40 = 25 + 10 + 5 vs 40 = 20 + 20).  It's still a useful algorithm, and it's how change is often made, but it doesn't match the description.

Comment: You're right. I completely overlooked this I'm afraid. Thanks for this.

Comment: @aloebys can you please clarify wrt Scott's comment?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for pointing out the flaw in my answer. I have updated it accordingly. Giving the least amount of change does make the problem harder to solve indeed. Pretty sure what I came up with isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you had a pretty good start already but there are a few things I'd change in order to make it more functional:

1. Use expressions rather than statements (e.g. no `return`)
2. Do not mutate data (e.g. no `n %= v`)

You don't necessarily need Ramda for this:

```js
const coins = value =>
  [25, 20, 10, 5, 1].reduce(([acc, val], cur) =>
    val < cur ? [acc, val] : [[...acc, [cur, Math.floor(val / cur)]], val % cur],
    [[], value]
  )[0];


console.log(coins(48));
console.log(coins(100));
```

If you find yourself using `map` then `filter`, you're most likely needing `reduce`. In my function `coins` above, the iterator returns an array that contains an array of pairs of coins and number of coins and the reduced value for each step.

Note that at each step I use a destructuring assignment to capture the array of pairs and the reduced value in individual parameters.

Now, it is of course possible to use Ramda for this as well:

```js
const {compose, filter, last, mapAccum, flip} = R;

const mapIterator = (a, b) => [a % b, [b, Math.floor(a / b)]];
const withCoins = ([coins, number]) => number > 0;
const coins = compose(filter(withCoins), last, flip(mapAccum(mapIterator))([25, 20, 10, 5, 1]));

console.log(coins(48));
console.log(coins(100));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**: as Scott rightly pointed out, any of my solutions above will give you the least amount of change.

This turned out to be more involved than I expected and I settled on a solution which I'm sure can be improved:

I define 5 sets of coins:

1. [1]
2. [5, 1]
3. [10, 5, 1]
4. [20, 10, 5, 1]
5. [25, 20, 10, 5, 1]

I compute how much change each set produces and keep only the one which produces the least.

For example to change `30`:

1. 1 × 30
2. 5 × 6
3. 10 × 3
4. **20 × 1, 10 × 1** (Keep this set)
5. 25 × 1, 5 × 1

```js
const {compose, pipe, sum, map, last, head, mapAccum, curry, flip, applyTo, sortBy, reject, not} = R;
const numCoins = compose(sum, map(last));
const changeFn = curry((coins, num) => mapAccum((cur, coin) => [cur % coin, [coin, Math.floor(cur / coin)]], num, coins)[1]);
const change1 = changeFn([1]);
const change2 = changeFn([5, 1]);
const change3 = changeFn([10, 5, 1]);
const change4 = changeFn([20, 10, 5, 1]);
const change5 = changeFn([25, 20, 10, 5, 1]);

const change = pipe(
  applyTo,
  flip(map)([
    change1,
    change2,
    change3,
    change4,
    change5]),
  sortBy(numCoins),
  head,
  reject(compose(not, last)));

console.log(change(30));
console.log(change(40));
console.log(change(48));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I find the ramda version far more readable, but YMMV. One nitpick: while reduce is certainly faster than mapping followed by filtering, the latter conveys the intent of the code (separation of concerns) in a way that the combined reduce doesn't. Compose lets you have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: +1 I felt it was important to let OP knows that they weren't that far-off in their original attempt. Having said that I'd certainly admit that the non-Ramda function feels more involved. Personally I'd also go with Ramda and compose functions.

Comment: I think these changes that generate the case `40 = 20 + 20` probably involve calculations that are necessary.  There is quite possibly a more elegant recursion, but that wouldn't change the number of calculations performed.

Answer (score 2):

This variant of the answer from user633183 will find the minimum number of coins, it doesn't use the common technique that chooses the maximum number of each larger denomination at the possible expense of choosing more coins overall.

Note that this can involve substantially more calculations than the original answers or the initial ones from customcommander.

`change` here returns a list of coin values, so for, say, `58` it will return `[25, 25, 5, 1, 1, 1]`.  `makeChange` converts that to the `[ [25, 2], [5, 1], [1, 3] ]` format.  If you change the `minLength` function from `<=` to `<`, then this would generate `[ [25, 1], [20, 1], [10, 1], [1, 3] ]`.  This is the same number of coins, but using different denominations.

If the order of the return doesn't matter to you, you could also remove the `sort` line.

The mix of styles here is somewhat unfortunate.  We could replace that Ramda pipeline version of `makeChange` with one more like `change` if we tried.  But I think in Ramda; this is what came most easily to mind.  Replacing `change` with a Ramda pipeline would not be as easy, as it's harder to do recursion in such a style.

---

**Thanks** to customcommander for pointing out a flaw in an earlier version of this answer.

---

```js
const minLength = (as, bs) =>
  as.length <= bs.length ? as : bs

const change = ([ c, ...rest ], amount = 0) => 
  amount === 0
    ? []
    : c === 1
      ? Array(amount).fill(1) 
      : c <= amount
        ? minLength (
          [ c, ...change ([c, ...rest], amount - c)],
          change (rest, amount)
        )
        : change (rest, amount)

const makeChange = pipe(
  change,
  countBy(identity),
  toPairs,
  map(map(Number)),
  sort(descend(head)) // if desired
)

const coins =
  [ 25, 20, 10, 5, 1 ]

console.log (makeChange (coins, 40))
//=> [ [ 20, 2 ] ]

console.log (makeChange (coins, 45))
//=> [ [ 25, 1 ], [ 20, 1 ] ]

console.log (change (coins, 48))
//=> [ [ 25, 1 ], [ 20, 1 ], [ 1, 3 ] ]

console.log (makeChange (coins, 100))
//=> [ [ 25, 4 ] ]
```

```html
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const { pipe, countBy, identity, toPairs, map, sort, descend, head } = R </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

People commonly reach for `map`, `filter`, and `reduce` but often the result is a bit of a square peg in a round hole.

- `map` doesn't makes sense because it's produces a 1-to-1 result; if I have 4 types of coins, I will always receive 4 types of change, which of course is not what we want. Use of `filter` forces you to do more processing to achieve the desired result.
- `reduce` can eliminate intermediate values caused by `map`+`filter`, but again, it's possible we will reach the desired result *before* having to analyze each coin. In the example of `fn(100)` which returns `[ [25, 4] ]`, there's no need to even look at coins `20`, `10`, `5`, or `1` because the result has already been reached; reducing further would be wasteful.

To me, functional programming is about convenience. If I don't have a function that does what I need, I simply make it, because it's important that my program clearly communicates its intention. Sometimes this means using a construct that's more suitable for datas I'm processing -

```
const change = (coins = [], amount = 0) =>

  loop                             // begin a loop, initializing:
    ( ( acc = []                   // an empty accumulator, acc
      , r = amount                 // the remaining amount to make change for, r
      , [ c, ...rest ] = coins     // the first coin, c, and the rest of coins
      ) =>

        r === 0                    // if the remainder is zero
          ? acc                    // return the accumulator

      : c <= r                     // if the coin is small enough
          ? recur                              // recur with
              ( [ ...acc, [ c, div (r, c) ] ]  // updated acc
              , mod (r, c)                     // updated remainder
              , rest                           // rest of coins
              )

                                   // otherwise (inductive) coin is too large
      : recur                      // recur with
          ( acc                    // unmodified acc
          , r                      // unmodified remainder
          , rest                   // rest of coins
          )

    )
```

Unlike `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`, our solution will *not* continue iterating over the input after the result has been determined. Using it looks like this -

```
const coins =
  [ 25, 20, 10, 5, 1 ]

console.log (change (coins, 48))
// [ [ 25, 1 ], [ 20, 1 ], [ 1, 3 ] ]

console.log (change (coins, 100))
// [ [ 25, 4 ] ]
```

Verify the results in your own browser below -

```js
const div = (x, y) =>
  Math .round (x / y)

const mod = (x, y) =>
  x % y

const recur = (...values) =>
  ({ recur, values })

const loop = f =>
{ let acc = f ()
  while (acc && acc.recur === recur)
    acc = f (...acc.values)
  return acc
}

const change = (coins = [], amount = 0) =>
  loop
    ( ( acc = []
      , r = amount
      , [ c, ...rest ] = coins
      ) =>
        r === 0
          ? acc
      : c <= r
          ? recur
              ( [ ...acc, [ c, div (r, c) ] ]
              , mod (r, c)
              , rest
              )
      : recur
          ( acc
          , r
          , rest
          )

    )

const coins =
  [ 25, 20, 10, 5, 1 ]

console.log (change (coins, 48))
// [ [ 25, 1 ], [ 20, 1 ], [ 1, 3 ] ]

console.log (change (coins, 100))
// [ [ 25, 4 ] ]
```

Ramda users can use `R.until`, though readability suffers due to it's purely function-driven interface. Flexibility of `loop` and `recur` is highly favourable, imo -

```
const change = (coins = [], amount = 0) =>
  R.until
    ( ([ acc, r, coins ]) => r === 0
    , ([ acc, r, [ c, ...rest ] ]) =>
        c <= r
          ? [ [ ...acc
              , [ c, Math.floor (R.divide (r, c)) ]
              ]
            ,  R.modulo (r, c)
            , rest
            ]
          : [ acc
            , r
            , rest
            ]
    , [ [], amount, coins ]
    )
    [ 0 ]
```

Another alternative is to write it as a recursive function -

```js
const div = (x, y) =>
  Math .round (x / y)

const mod = (x, y) =>
  x % y

const change = ([ c, ...rest ], amount = 0) =>
  amount === 0
    ? []
: c <= amount
    ? [ [ c, div (amount, c) ]
      , ...change (rest, mod (amount, c))
      ]
: change (rest, amount)

const coins =
  [ 25, 20, 10, 5, 1 ]

console.log (change (coins, 48))
// [ [ 25, 1 ], [ 20, 1 ], [ 1, 3 ] ]

console.log (change (coins, 100))
// [ [ 25, 4 ] ]
```

Comment: I think the recursive portion here is the cleanest answer... but only if the goal is 40 = 25 + 10 + 5 and not 40 = 20 + 20 as I mentioned above.  If it's the latter, then I think an entirely different approach would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Scott. I wasn't totally happy with other portions of the answer, but the cost to improve them outweighed the added impact I felt the improvements would make. `40 = 20 + 20` is indeed significantly more difficult. If that is what the OP needs, I'm happy to extend the answer.